# NetLogo - selecting edge patches of patch-set

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to select the patches along the edge of a contiguous `patch-set` but am having trouble doing so. The patch-sets represent territories of animals. All patches in the territory touch another patch in the territory. I thought I could select the `neighbors4` of the territory `patch-set` and then ask those neighbors to in turn select their neighbors that belong to the territory. That way just the edge of the territory would theoretically be selected. It runs but does not appear to select the right patches. Here is the code snippet I'm working with:

```
let neighbor-test no-patches
let territory-edge no-patches    
ask territory 
  [ 
    ; assign owning animal to territory patches        
    set owner-animal calling-animal  
    set neighbor-test (patch-set neighbors4 with [owner-animal != calling-animal])
    ask neighbor-test
    [
     set territory-edge (patch-set neighbors4 with [owner-animal = calling-animal])
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your situation correctly, any patch of the territory that has a neighbor outside the territory is an edge. And "outside the territory" means not having the same owner. One way to express this in NetLogo would be:

```
patches-own [ owner-animal ]

to-report edge-patches [ territory ]
  report territory with [
    any? neighbors with [
      owner-animal != [ owner-animal ] of myself
    ]
  ]
end
```

And here is a fun little demonstration, to see it in action:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask n-of (2 + random 8) patches [
    sprout 1 [
      let territory patches in-radius (2 + random 8)
      ask territory [
        set owner-animal myself
        set pcolor [ color ] of myself - 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    let territory patches with [ owner-animal = myself ]
    ask edge-patches territory [      
      set pcolor [ color ] of myself + 2
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Sorry I don't think I explained it well. I mean to select patches along the inside edge of the territory. So they would have `owner-male = myself`.  The idea is that the animal will drop patches of lowest quality from its own territory (from along the inner edge) as it finds better patches outside its territory that it wants to add to its own territory.

Comment: The patches selected by `edge-patches` _are_ along the inside edge of the territory. The code looks for patches that have a _neighbor_ with `owner-animal != [ owner-animal ] of myself`. If you run `show [ owner-animal ] of territory` and then `show [ owner-animal ] of edges-patches territory`, you'll see that the edges have the same owner as the territory. Or I am really not understanding you correctly?

Comment: Ah, I see now! Yes, this is totally correct. Sorry I was a dunce before. This is so straightforward too. Thanks again.